# Retrieving information and image from database in grails

Tags: grails

I have a domain class called Product. I have saved the information and image in database.  But while retrieving information, I retrieved the all the information but could not retrieve image.

`Domain Class`

```
class Product {

        String productName    
        String description    
        int price    
        byte [] photo
        String phototype
    }

I have saved the information and image in database using this action in ProductController. In gsp page, I used <g:uploadForm> tag to get information.



def saveProduct(){

    def pic = request.getFile('picture')
    product.properties['productName','description','price'] = params
    product.photo=pic.bytes
    product.phototype=pic.contentType

    if(!product.save()){
        render (view: "/adminPanel", model: [upload: "Product Failed to Upload",product:product])
        return
    }
    else {
        render (view: "/adminPanel", model: [upload: "Product Successfully Saved!!",product: product])
    }
}
```

This code saved the information and image in database. Now, how can I display image and product informations in adminPanel.gsp page? What sort of code should I write in controller and gsp page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using plugin for that. 
**[Avatar uploader](https://grails.org/wiki/Simple%20Avatar%20Uploader)** is a good one.

> Simple avatar uploader - Grails makes the upload and display of these images almost trivial.

Comment: @Sagar if you think my answer is good for your question, accept it by clicking checkmark on the right side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can show your image which is stored in `DB` pretty simply.

Just add one action for retrieving the image from table and sent it to `GSP`

```
class ProductController {

    def saveProduct(){
    .......
    }    

    /** Action for fetching the image byte array
        Assuming that you have passed the "productName" from UI 
        to fetch the particular product image
     */
    def fetchProductImage(){
        def product = Product.findByProductName(params.productName)
        byte[] imageInByte = product.photo
        response.contentType = 'image/png' // or the appropriate image content type
        response.outputStream << imageInByte
        response.outputStream.flush()
    }        
}
```

And give call to this controller action from `GSP View` like below :

```
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'product', action: 'fetchProductImage', params: ['productName': 'Some_product_name'])}"/>
```

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem then you can accept it by clicking on the green tick and also you can upvote it by clicking on the up arrow.